# Can't access SharedPreferences from my Service

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**What I'm trying to do**

---

Hello Guys.

I got a Service which, set's a boolean to true or to false whenever the service is started or stopped (started = true / stopped = false) in the SharedPreference. Now when I try to get the Boolean out there in my Activity, it allways dosn't find it. How can I solve this... Here's the Code for you Guys.

**Code**

---

Methode in my Service:

```
private void setStarted(boolean started) {
    // SharedPreferences casten

    mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(LOG_TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Boolean in SharedPreferences hinzufügen
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.clear().apply();
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_STARTED, started).commit();
    editor.commit();

    //mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(PREF_STARTED, started).commit();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Variabel " + mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_STARTED, false));
}
```

In my Activity

```
// mPrefs caten
        mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(GPSService.LOG_TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);

        // boolean holen ob service gestartet oder nicht
        run = mPrefs.getBoolean(GPSService.PREF_STARTED, false);
```

How do I get the boolean out of there? It allways returns me the default value I had to give in the getBoolean Methode.

Thanks for your help in advance

safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that I'm successfully using in one of my apps. It is used in various parts of the app, e.g. both from activities and services:

```
void putValue(Context context, String pref, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(pref, value);
    editor.commit();                
}

boolean getValue(Context context, String value, boolean defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return settings.getBoolean(value, defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using  getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context) method of [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) in both your services and your activities.

```
private void setStarted(boolean started) {

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(PREF_STARTED, started).commit();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Variabel " + mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_STARTED, false));
}
```

In your Activity

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);    
run = mPrefs.getBoolean(GPSService.PREF_STARTED, false);
```

Also make sure you :

- Never call .clear() on editor.
- You use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) everywhere.

Comment: how should this look like and why can't I use the SharedPreferences? Please improve your anwser :D thx!

Comment: You can use shared preferences in both activity and service, there is no problem. :)

Comment: So if I understood this right i can use this line "mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);" of code in both activites and get out the values like i did it before? Right=

Comment: Ok. I remeber having some troubles like you with SharedPreferences and boolean. Let me check what i did to solve it.

Comment: What I see from my Logs, the Service writes in the right value, but I get allways the false value out.....

Comment: Are you sure that the setStarted method is called before trying to retrieve the value ?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. When you call set started. The log just after shows the correct value right ? Try to add logs in your activity to see if the order of the service calls and activity calls is correct.

Comment: the log in the methode setStarted... allways shows the correct value... but when i try to get the value over the sharedpreferences its allways wrong.... it allways puts in the default value.... :(

Comment: Is there anywhere else you call editor.clear() ? Cause you should not call this at all. (It removes all the current preferences !) And make sure you use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) to access prefrences everywhere !

Answer (score 1):

Just build your prefs object the same way you would as part of your activity. The only difference is pulling your application's context in.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = _ getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.appname", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

Boolean tmpBool = prefs.getBoolean("PREF_NAME", null);
```